# Restangular.copy(): route on .one() object ends up undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I'm having problems with Restangular's **.one()** and **.put()** functions. When I **Restangular.copy()** the element I need to work with, I lose the **route** value.

If I manually add the **route** value I get it to work (example down below).

My plan was to use resolves in **$stateProvider**, but this is still in testing-phase, that's why I'm looking for advice/need help.

Am I doing something completely wrong?

---

### API side:

```
GET: /api/news/1
```

#### Response:

```
{
  "success":true,
  "status":200,
  "data": [
    {"id": 1, "title":"the title", "author":"the author", "date": 123456789, "contents": "the contents"}
  ]
}
```

---

### Front-end side:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'restangular'])
.config(['RestangularProvider', '$stateProvider', function (RestangularProvider, $stateProvider) {
  RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('/api');

  RestangularProvider.addResponseInterceptor(function (data, operation) {
    var extractedData;

    if (operation === 'getList') {
      extractedData         = data.data;
      extractedData.success = data.success;
      extractedData.status  = data.status;
    } else {
      extractedData = data;
    }

    return extractedData;
  });

  $stateProvider.state('news', {
    url: '/news/:id',
    views: {
      'articles': {
        controller: 'NewsCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'news-view.html'
      }
    }
  });
}])
.controller('NewsCtrl', ['$stateParams', 'Restangular', function ($stateParams, Restangular) {

  $stateParams.id = 1; // For the sake of this example

  Restangular.one('news', $stateParams.id).get().then(function (data) {
    console.log(data); // route set to news

    var post   = data.data[0]; // access the response object
    post.title = 'a news title';
    post.put(); // TypeError: undefined is not a function

    var anotherPost   = Restangular.copy(data.data[0]); // using Restangular.copy instead
    anotherPost.title = 'another news title';
    // anotherPost.route = 'news'; // if I add this to anotherPost, put() will work
    anotherPost.put(); // /api/undefined/1 404 (Not found)
  });

}]);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should follow these instructions to improve parsing of your entities before using the method

https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#my-response-is-actually-wrapped-with-some-metadata-how-do-i-get-the-data-in-that-case

```
app.config(function(RestangularProvider) {

// add a response intereceptor
RestangularProvider.addResponseInterceptor(function(data, operation, what, url, response, deferred) {
  var extractedData;
  // .. to look for getList operations
  if (operation === "getList") {
    // .. and handle the data and meta data
    extractedData = data.data.data;
    extractedData.meta = data.data.meta;
  } else {
    extractedData = data.data;
  }
  return extractedData;
});
```

});